# Has installation been successful or there is any error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

This is the command prompt where I am installing the tensor flow in Anaconda:

[image: This is the command prompt where I am installing the tensor flow in Anaconda]

I am new to Python and I want to use Tensorflow. But on installing TensorFlow inside Anaconda, I am shown this on validating the installation process.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7500) with TensorFlow 1.0 on Windows. The error messages are harmless, you did nothing wrong, and you can ignore them.

The issue has been fixed in TensorFlow 1.1, for which a release candidate was just published. You can upgrade to it by running the following command at the command prompt:

```
C:\> pip install --upgrade tensorflow==1.1.0rc0
```